# how to set limit max widget in row flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have controller generated like this

```
final inputs = List.generate(100, (i) => TextEditingController());
```

and the input inside row

```
Row: (
children: [

  Expanded(
      child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
      child: TextField(
                                
                                
       autocorrect: false,
      
       controller: inputs[1], <= here is controller define
                               
    )),
]);
```

if I use for loop then row input become 100 in single row

I want max 5 input in one row

Here is screenshot
[image]

how to achieve this
thank you

Comment: using `GridView` widget

Comment: text editing controller update with `TextEditingController(text: "$i")); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `GridView`

```
GridView.count(  
                crossAxisCount: 5,  
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,  
                mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,  
                children: List.generate(inputs.length, (index) {  
                  return Center(  
                    child: ,// your widget  
                  );  
                }  
                )
```